# problem EXC_BAD_ACCESS with "removeFromSuperView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, exc-bad-access

I have a problem on xcode. When my image(image1) collide with image2 I want to remove it with removefromsuperview but when I run my app there is an error " EXC_BAD_ACCESS " , I think it is due to removefromsuperview. How can I solve this ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the object you are calling removeFromSuperView does not exist, or was previously released.

Make sure you are sending the message to a valid object.

Comment: How can we make sure the the object is valid?

Answer (score 3):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that you're using an object after it has been released. Use Xcode's Analyzer (CMD+A) to find where or use the debugger with the `NSZombieEnabled` flag.

If you want me to write this in French, comment and I'll translate :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this because I had removed all CALayers from the view before trying to remove it from superview. Both `self.layer.sublayers = nil` and iterating over them all caused the problem. Worked perfectly when the view was instantiated programmatically but when I instantiated one from storyboard it apparently had weak pointers to other layers that I didn't know about.

Solution? I kept track of all my own layers and removed them one at a time instead of assuming all layers in `self.layer.sublayers` were mine.